# Every three noncollinear $x, y, z\in S,\exists! p\in S:\overline{xp}\text{ , }\overline{yp}\text{ , }\overline{zp} \in S \Longrightarrow| \ker(S) |=1$

Tags: convex-geometry

**Problem**:
Let $\displaystyle{S}$ be a subset of $\displaystyle{\mathbb{E}^{n}}$.
Suppose that $\displaystyle{S}$ contains at least three points that are not collinear,
and suppose that for every three noncollinear points $\displaystyle{x , y , z}$ in $S$
there exists a unique point $p$ in $S$ such that $\displaystyle{\overline{xp} \text{ , } \overline{yp}}$, and $\displaystyle{\overline{zp}}$ all lie in $S$.
Prove that the kernel of $S$ consists of a single point.

**Solution**:
The kernel of the set $S$ is $\displaystyle{K = \ker(S) = \big \{ x \in S : \overline{x y} \in S , \forall y \in S \big \}}$.
\
We know that: $K$ is convex set.
\
Since $\displaystyle{S}$ contains at least three points $\displaystyle{x , y , z \in S}$ that are not collinear, then there exists unique $p \in S$ such that $\displaystyle{\overline{p x} \text{ , } \overline{p y} \text{ , } \overline{p z} \in S
}$.
\
Suppose by contradiction that: $|K| \geqslant 2$. Let $\displaystyle{a , b \in K}$.
\
But then $\displaystyle{
\begin{cases}
\overline{a x} \text{ , } \overline{a y} \text{ , } \overline{a z} \in S
\\
\\
\overline{b x} \text{ , } \overline{b y} \text{ , } \overline{b z} \in S
\end{cases}}$,
which is a contradiction, because there is an unique $\displaystyle{p}$ with this property.
Therefore $\displaystyle{| K | \leqslant 1 \Longrightarrow K = \varnothing}$ or $\displaystyle{| K | = 1}$.

Assume by contradiction that: $\displaystyle{K = \varnothing \Longrightarrow \forall u \in S : \exists v \in S , \overline{u v} \notin S}$.

***My question is: How can we prove that $|K|=1$?***

***I was thinking that $p \in K$, but is it correct?***